# Android fastclick issue

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, fastclick.js

I have two different pages with a clickable element
located on the same position. On the first page there is 
a menu button which will open up if a user clicks on it and 
on the second one, in the exact same position there is a back 
button which will redirect the user to the first page.

Now to the problem; whenever a user clicks the back
button on the second page he will be redirected to the
first page which is intended, but it will also open
up the menu automatically which it shouldn't do.

I am building an app with PhoneGap where i am utilizing
the fastclick library in order to eliminate the 300ms click 
delay. If the fastclick library isn't used, the 
application works as expected but then it wont feel as responsive.

The fastclick library works perfectly under iOS environment.

What could be causing this undesirable effect?

Comment: which android/phonegap version are you testing on? Using fastclick on Android 4.4.x  has this issue.

Comment: I have tested this on both Android 4.3 and 4.1.2 with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is more because the click on loaded on a mouse event and not a touch event that you are experiencing this issue. Can you try loading the event handler on a touch event instead ?

Comment: I have tried both as a regular click event and a touch event if that was what you were referring to, both produced the same results. After some research i've found out that this seems to be a common problem that goes under the name of ghost clicks. https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick/issues/130