# Phonegap - touch being carried over to next page

Tags: cordova

In my phonegap app, when I tap a button to go to next page, an element (in the same spot) in the next page are also being tapped.

My code is as simple as this:

```
<a href="page2.html" class="button"> Next </a>
```

How do I solve this issue? Is this a common issue because when I search google I only find *"handling double tap"* articles.

I'm using:

- touchpunch.js
- fastclick.js.
- Cordova 3.4.0
- Jquery 1.4.2

Comment: have a look over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013099/android-fastclick-issue#comment38895145_25013099) for similar issue. Have you used fastclik.js in your app? Are you using jquery? what version of cordova/phonegap, jquery are you working on?

Comment: Thanks, but it remains unsolved. I am using touchpunch.js and fastclick.js, I am using cordova 3.4.0 and jquery 1.4.2

I'll update my question.

Comment: If you are testing on android 4.4.x version than you can try to **remove** the fastclick.js and check whether it resolve the issue.

Comment: Yes this resolved the issue, but i need fastclick to remove the 300ms click delay on mobile devices.